# How do I center my navigation bar and background across the screen?

Tags: html, css

I am going crazy trying to center my Nav Bar on top of my page on my website http://www.custombarres.com
I would like the #ddd bkgd-color to fill the entire width of the screen. I also would like the nav bar to be responsive and resize with the screen size, while the text remains centered on the screen.  I would like to do the same with my other Menu bar below. This is a BigCommerce site and the files are all over the place...
Please help,

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: You should be using a debugger like firebug to figure this type of simple thing out on your own. The .container that your top bar is in is set at a fixed with. You'll need to set it to width 100% for the top bar to go across.